# codeigniter extract stdClass Object

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm using codeigniter, here's my view :

```
        <select name="kode_promo_air" id="kode_promo_air" class="span3 input2">
            <option value="">-PILIH-</option>
            <?php
            $data = $this->app_model->get_promo_air();  

            foreach($data->result() as $t){
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $t->PRO_PRICE_CODE;?>"><?php echo $t->PRO_MST_NM;?> - <?php echo $t->PRO_AMT_CUST;?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
```

and here's app_model -> get_promo_air()

```
function get_promo_air()
{
    $sql = "
                SELECT
                    c.PRO_PRICE_CODE,
                    a.PRO_MST_NM,
                    c.PRO_AMT_CUST
                FROM
                    promo_master a
                inner join  promo_type b on a.pro_type_id = b.pro_type_id
                inner join  promo_price c on a.PRO_MST_ID = c.PRO_MST_ID 
                WHERE sysdate() BETWEEN a.PRO_PRICE_DATE_FROM
                AND a.PRO_PRICE_DATE_TO
                AND b.PRO_TYPE_ID = 1       
            ";

    return $this->db->query($sql);  

}
```

the problem is i can't get $data->result() in my view, when i debug :

```
<?php
                    $data = $this->app_model->get_promo_air();  

                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($data->result());
                    die();

?>              

                <select name="kode_promo_air" id="kode_promo_air" class="span3 input2">
                    <option value="">-PILIH-</option>
                    <?php
                    $data = $this->app_model->get_promo_air();  

                    foreach($data->result() as $t){
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $t->PRO_PRICE_CODE;?>"><?php echo $t->PRO_MST_NM;?> - <?php echo $t->PRO_AMT_CUST;?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

i've got :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [PRO_PRICE_CODE] => AAA001001
            [PRO_MST_NM] => Promo Air Asia
            [PRO_AMT_CUST] => 65000.00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [PRO_PRICE_CODE] => AGI001001
            [PRO_MST_NM] => Promo Garuda
            [PRO_AMT_CUST] => 40000.00
        )

)
```

how to get the value ? coz i try with `foreach($data->result() as $t)` it's can't get the data... any solution would be appreciated..

Comment: Have provided with a solution for the request that you have asked the question. Have a try and share thoughts.

Answer (score 5):

Try to return `result array` like

```
return $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
```

Or in foreach loop try like

```
foreach ($data->result_array() as $t) {
    // Do the stuff
}
```

Comment: just print the `$data` and tell me

Comment: just like above sir, here's Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [PRO_PRICE_CODE] => AAA001001
            [PRO_MST_NM] => Promo Air Asia
            [PRO_AMT_CUST] => 65000.00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [PRO_PRICE_CODE] => AGI001001
            [PRO_MST_NM] => Promo Garuda
            [PRO_AMT_CUST] => 40000.00
        )

)

Comment: Then try with my second answer

Comment: i'll try again, it's get error : Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 3):

return result_array();
this will solve the problem.

output

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Jared Leto
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Scott Eastwood
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Kate Mara
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => Holland Roden
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT
             c.PRO_PRICE_CODE
             a.PRO_MST_NM,
             c.PRO_AMT_CUST
                FROM
                    promo_master a
                inner join  promo_type b on a.pro_type_id = b.pro_type_id
                inner join  promo_price c on a.PRO_MST_ID = c.PRO_MST_ID 
                WHERE sysdate() BETWEEN a.PRO_PRICE_DATE_FROM
                AND a.PRO_PRICE_DATE_TO
                AND b.PRO_TYPE_ID = 1       
            ";

$query = $this->db-query($sql);
return $query;
```

or

```
return $query->result();
```

If you use `return $query->result()`, you would only need the variable name in `foreach`.

```
$data = $this->app_model->get_promo_air(); 

foreach($data as $t){

//Your code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->result();=$t=

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [PRO_PRICE_CODE] => AAA001001
            [PRO_MST_NM] => Promo Air Asia
            [PRO_AMT_CUST] => 65000.00
        )

   [1].........
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$t[0]=stdClass Object
        (
            [PRO_PRICE_CODE] => AAA001001
            [PRO_MST_NM] => Promo Air Asia
            [PRO_AMT_CUST] => 65000.00
        )
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$t[0]->PRO_PRICE_CODE; = AAA001001
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution.

When executed, the row_array is returns twice as many desired results.  For example, if  `content` is the input, the output is `content content`. Then I put the `|` in the `$lastone`, to remove with the explosion and separate the two.

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $row = $query->row_array(); 

        $lastone= $row['column']."|";
    }

    list ($last, $before) = explode ("|", $lastone);

return $last;
```

Answer (score 0):

**model -->**
in app_model, return result like this.

```
return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
```

**View -->**
then you can get data like this.

```
<?php foreach($data as $key): ?>

           <p>PRO_PRICE_CODE : <?php echo $key->PRO_PRICE_CODE; ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [PRO_PRICE_CODE] => AAA001001
            [PRO_MST_NM] => Promo Air Asia
            [PRO_AMT_CUST] => 65000.00
        )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [PRO_PRICE_CODE] => AGI001001
        [PRO_MST_NM] => Promo Garuda
        [PRO_AMT_CUST] => 40000.00
    )
```

)

You can print individually using 
print($data_stdClass[0]->PRO_PRICE_CODE);

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($data['0']->PRO_PRICE_CODE);  //you will get AAA001001
print_r($data['0']->PRO_PRICE_CODE);  //you will get AAA001001
print_r($data['0']->PRO_MST_NM);      //you will get Promo Air Asia
print_r($data['0']->PRO_AMT_CUST);    //you will get 65000.00
```

Similarly,

```
print_r($data['1']->PRO_PRICE_CODE);  //you will get AGI001001
```